# Convert Jsonb simple array into column group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a simple table with a Jsonb array of phone numbers:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_info (
    id serial,
    phone_numbers jsonb
);
INSERT INTO user_info values (1, '["123456"]'),(2, '["564789"]'), (3, '["564747", "545884"]');
```

**SQLFiddle**: [SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f766b/1/0)

now, I want to group the array of numbers into columns.
something like:

| phone_numbers | id |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 |
| 564789 | 2 |
| 564747 | 3 |
| 545884 | 3 |

I have tried the below query but it is not working:

```
select s.phone_numbers
from (
        select id,phone_numbers from sales_order_details,
         lateral jsonb_array_elements(phone_numbers) e
     ) s
group by s.phone_numbers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to nest queries:

```
select pn.phone_number,
       ui.id
from user_info ui 
  cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(ui.phone_numbers) as pn(phone_number)
order by ui.id
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8e1c29c457a0d3ccb7f2ef196844bf68)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with the outer group by, but the following gives you the raw data

```
select id,e.value phone_number from user_info,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(phone_numbers) e
```